# Elasticsearch query while indexing

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 3 nodes (3 shards) of elasticsearch, one index, which contains 26m documents. Index operations perform every 100ms. 
If indexing is turned on, then my search query performs ~ 1,5s.
If indexing is turned off, then the same query gives  ~ 100-150ms.

So, while indexing is turned on, my search query is 10 times slower.

What can I do to increase speed of my queries if indexing is online ?

Comment: If you don't actually need to include the freshly indexed items in your searches right away (by default, the refresh is performed every second), you can increase the refresh time per index: `POST /my_index/_settings
{ "refresh_interval": "10s" }`. This is a dynamic setting that can be changed on the fly. Try increasing the refresh interval and see what response times you get.

Comment: My current refresh interval is 30 seconds, I've tried 60 second, but result is the same.

Comment: What is RAM size? and How much HEAP size assign for jvm?

Comment: Each node has 16gb ram, and heap size is 9gb.

Comment: Your heap should really be 8 GB. I suggest making the change and test again.

Comment: I've tested all variants of heap size. from 2 gb to 14 gb, the result is the same, query is 10 times slower when new documents  indexing is turned on.

Comment: if I divide index into two - main and current day, then search will be fast, but in my case it is very hard to union serach results in right way. I do not understand what I'm doing wrong, that my elatistic performes so slow search if I index new documents.